# Python3: tabula-py imports several strings with random whitespaces

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tabula-py

I'm not sure if this behaviour's normal, but there is some inconsistency while reading the pdf.

A oneliner: `pdf = tabula.read_pdf(path, pages=pages)`

Where `path` is the directory of the pdf file. When printing the `pdf` in the console some values like e.g. *Ceiling materials*, the next line parsed has whitespaces like e.g. *C eiling ma terials*.

Here is a picture:

[image]

The same happens to a series of numbers, they're imported with whitespaces too.

Does anyone know why this is the case? And possibly how to avoid the redundant whitespaces?

I mean, it doesn't make sense that one line is parsed perfectly fine whilst the other's not. Bug?

Comment: NB: I'm using tabula-py 2.2.0 and Python 3.8.1